# Load data from URL to update Billboard position Cesium

Tags: jquery, cesium, ajax

I am trying to update the position of a billboard every second in Cesium. The issue is I cannot pass the updating points to the billboard coordinates. I am using jQuery to load the data. This is what I have

```
//getting values every second
window.setInterval(function nameSat()
        {
         $.getJSON('http://10.175.129.10/meo_coordinates_heo.json', function(data) 
            {
                 lat1 =`${data[0].Latitude  }`
                 lon1 =`${data[0].Longitude }`
                 alt1 =`${data[0].Altitude *1000 }`
                 active1 =`${data[0].Active }`

                var lat = parseInt(lat1);
                var lon = parseInt(lon1);
                var alt = parseInt(alt1);
            })

    }, 1000);


//i want to put the updating coordinates here
function addBillboard() {

    Sandcastle.declare(addBillboard);
viewer.entities.add({
        position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(lon180, 40,8000000),
        billboard :{
         scale : 0.03,
            image : '../images/sat.png'
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there more than one object/billboard, or do you want just a single billboard to get its position updated every second?  Also, does the server know the upcoming positions in advance, or is it live tracking something?  I ask because there are ways to download a full path as opposed to live-updated positions.

Comment: There is more than 1 billboard updating, I only put one as an example. The server will receive updated values every second but it doesnt have a record of what data will be coming in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anybody who might be having an issue similar to me i have found a solution based on a tutorial from https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Picking.html.

My solution based on this is below:

```
function addMultipleBillboards() {
   Sandcastle.declare(addMultipleBillboards);
    var satelliteURL = '../images/sat.png';
    var facilityUrl = '../images/facility.gif';

//create the billboard first
var satellite1 = viewer.entities.add(
{
    billboard :
    {
        scale:0.08,
         pixelOffset : new Cesium.Cartesian2(0, -30),
        image : satelliteURL
    },
    label:
    {
        id: 'MEO_M003',
        text: 'MEO_M003',
        fillColor: Cesium.Color.AQUAMARINE,
        font: '12px Times New Roman',
        outlineWidth :3
    }
});

//the do the call for getting data
window.setInterval(function nameSat()
        {
         $.getJSON('http://10.175.129.10/meo_coordinates_heo.json', function(data) 
            {
                 lat1 =`${data[0].Latitude  }`
                 lon1 =`${data[0].Longitude }`
                 alt1 =`${data[0].Altitude *1000}`

//i need to parse my data because its a string
var meo_lat1 =parseFloat(lat1);
                 var meo_lon1 =parseFloat(lon1);
                 var meo_alt1 =parseFloat(alt1);

//once parsed, set the position inside the interval 
satellite1.position=Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(meo_lon1,meo_lat1,meo_alt1);
}
```